# Permanently Hide SD

Tags: macos, finder, sd-card

I have a jetdrive that i'm using permanently in my macbook air SD card slot. I'm wanting to make it so that the drive does not show up in my desktop or sidebar, but is accessible through a folder. I have the folder set up there for it, but can't seem to make the drive disappear from my desktop.

I don't want to use the finder method of hiding ALL drives, it is only this drive with the specific name / file system UUID.

I have tried using the `chflags hidden '/Volume/DRIVE'`, however this does not persist through a computer reboot. I did have this working in the past but recently had to reformat the SD card and now it is not working anymore.

I am running a Macbook Air Mid 2013 with OSX El Capitan (10.11)

Answer (score 1):

Finder --> Preferences --> then uncheck "External disks" from both General and Sidebar tab.

Comment: that's only good if you want *no* external disks to show

Answer (score 0):

You could make a script (either shell script or AppleScript) that hides the Volume and make it run on login as a "Login Item" (in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Your User > Login Items).

Shell script may have to invoke Terminal in some way, otherwise you can apparently [hide icons via AppleScript](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/can-you-hide-specific-icons-on-the-desktop.1002566/) (which can be turned into a standalone app):

```
tell app "System Events" to set visible of disk DRIVE to false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing (or creating) `/etc/fstab`
This lets you mount the file at a specified mount point.

If you look at this file you will see the following warning:-

```
#
# Warning - this file should only be modified with vifs(8)
#
# Failure to do so is unsupported and may be destructive.
#
```

This is not a problem, but you need to learn how to use the `vi` editor and understand the `fstab` command line  (`man fstab` will explain this).

If this does not sound too formidable, and you need further help ask, giving details of mount point, file system and UUID.

Comment: My /etc/fstab file doesn't exist at the moment (using vi /etc/fstab). I have no worries finding the UUID and mount point - but will this allow it to be accessible via a direct folder (/Volumes/device) but just not visible on the desktop or sidebar? When i looked into the fstab file it seemed to suggest it stopped volumes being mounted (i want it to be mounted just not readily visible)

Comment: I don't know about a new OS X install (mine is 4 years old) but it was there then. I mainly use this to stop automounting of partitions I don't want.  An example I use (on Linux)  `UUID=*******      /mnt/PiData     ext4    defaults,noatime,noauto  0     0` NOTE You can use ANY directory (which exists) as mount point. I can't be sure, but I think the builtin automount is responsible for showing on the desktop etc. Give it a try!

Answer (score -2):

The issue is, newer mac uses PCIe bus, and SD Cards connected to it are treated as internal storage, however, we can't hide internal SD card except internal HDD...

There is a check box, which I used while using Yosemite, however, since I cleaned installed Sierra... I am searching for that option, will post again when I get it.

Comment: This is very confused & potentially misleading. Are you confusing SD & SSD perhaps?